# angular directive template not showing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I created a directive on angular with the following code below:

```
app.directive('uploader', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        template: '<div class="col-md-12">'
                    + '<p><input type="file" id= "file_upload" name="file_upload" class="fullWidth" />'
                    + '</p>'
                + '</div>'
                + '< br /><br/>'
                + '<div class="modal-footer">'
        + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="upload()">Import File</button >'
        + '< /div>'
```

And used it with my html code below:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="importModal" role="dialog">
    <div id="importRealModal" class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="dateModalTitle">Import Workflow</h4>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-body" uploader>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem here is that my div with the class of `modal-body` is not rendering the template on my directive.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared it as element directive. So use it like

```
<uploader></uploader>
```

Comment: Or else, directive can be declared as `restrict: 'AE',`